# Install Google Chrome without "sudo" on Ubuntu 22 server

Tags: ubuntu, selenium-webdriver

I need to install Google Chrome on an Ubuntu 22 server to run Selenium (a library for webscraping).

The problem is that I'm on a shared server without the permission to use "sudo".

Now I'm searching for a way to install Google Chrome without having root access.

Is there any possibility or workaround to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the .deb file from here: https://www.google.com/chrome/?platform=linux. Then run this command where `dir` is a directory that you have write access to and is in your path. You can try `~/.local/bin` for dir.

```
dpkg -x [insert path to chrome .deb file] dir
```

if you do not have dpkg do the following:

```
mkdir chrome
cp google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb chrome/
cd chrome
ar x google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
tar xvf data.tar.xz
opt/google/chrome/chrome
```

this will run chrome but not install it. you need dpkg to install the `.deb` file properly, but in order to install `dpkg` you need root perms and apt. have someone with root access run `sudo apt install dpkg -y` and retry .

Comment: I've downloaded the file and uploaded it in a folder with write access. But it doesn't work. I've edited my initial post so you can check. Thanks.

Comment: @Zerers I have updated my answer, please have someone with root access install dpkg but temporarily you can use my fix inorder to run chrome.

Comment: Not even "ar" commands are working. So to make it short. Without root access a Google Chrome installation is not possible, right?

Comment: @Zerers yeah, unless you want to build it from source but that is a super advanced and long process.